Disk mounts but when using fstab gives: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock
Background
This might not be pertinent:
I installed a newly downloaded iso of fedora server 40 on an ssd and began to configure. So far so good.
One of the things we've found about ssds is they live a lot longer, and you're at less risk of data loss when things go wrong, if you move heavy write activity off of them, so, for this system, we have a companion enterprise class drive... We created three partitions, one for /tmp one for /var and a third for the rest of the space.
Normally the procedure is to prepare the spinning disk, make a copy of /var, /tmp if you want, etc, then sit there and wait for the chance tell it not to reboot normally but give a root-login prompt. Then, from the console, one does an mv of /tmp and /var to /tmp.orig, /var.orig, make new mount directories and then boot into the new partitions.
However, for the first time ever I tried doing the followup "remotely" via ssh and on reboot it didn't come up.
I suspected it was because it didn't have empty mount points; though I've never had it complain about that before, and boot anyway, I have found it DOES sometimes cause some weird effects. So "do it right," I figured.
The Current Problem
However, no, something else is wrong. None of the three partitions mount during boot, nor does the non /tmp, non /var partition mount with a simple mount command of either, however, as a simple diagnostic, I skipped the UUIDs and all three mount to different locations than specified in /etc/fstab by this:
mount /dev/sdb1 /disks/var
mount /dev/sdb2 /disks/tmp
mount /dev/sdb3 /disks/users

I can't readily capture the output from mount during boot, though I did try, but the short of it is I returned the system to the original configuration, booted, restored the fstab entries but pointing at alternative mount points and simple mount -mount-point- syntax all failed with:
mount: /disks/users: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Bad UUIDs, right? So I went back to the default /var and /tmp trees and tried commenting out any competing entries and created this fstab entry:
/dev/sdb3 /disks/users ext4 default 1 1

Frustratingly, I got the same error! BUT, when I tried the more full syntax of mount, providing both the old-school /dev path (not UUID) and mount point, they all three mount just fine?!
Since UUIDs seem to be ruled out, only in the interest of being complete do I cite that I got the UUIDs from:
blkid | grep UUID= > /tmp/UUIDs

Helpfully, though, the same command returns the file system type and all three report as
TYPE="ext4"

...
Prompted by JaromandaX, I investigated /proc/mounts during a time when the disks are mounted manually.
/proc/mounts is a link that points to /proc/self/mounts. In /proc/self, there are three entries starting with mount: mounts, mountinfo and mountstats. A cat of mounts gives all the mounted "devices" and adding a grep yields this line: /dev/sdb3 /disks/users ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
Noting that the fstab entry included two numeral 1s and not zeros, I changed an fstab entry to use zeros and tried again but it didn't help.

Have you determined those "disks" are ext4 filesystems?

@JaromandaX I strontly prefer ext4, created them thus and blkid says they are; what else am I to do to confirm it? (There is no gui, this is Fedora Server, but there are many CLI tools; which one do you believe more than blkid?)

I strontly prefer ext4 I never suggested you should use anything else - I just asked if you would confirm that they are - what else am I to do to confirm it? nothing, you only need to confirm it once - sorry, I missed the last part of your question - it's all over the place and hard to follow to be honest

@JaromandaX Sorry about that; in the past, people have complained that I hadn't told them how I got into the scenario I was asking about... I guess I could have labeled it "background," or something like that. I surely don't mean to confuse!

So, mounting on the command line works? just when you use fstab it doesn't? That's the part I'm not 100% sure about

After successfully mounting the filesystems on the command line, how do the corresponding /proc/mounts lines look like? That should confirm the actual device path, filesystem type and options used.

@telcoM I'll check, thanks!

@JaromandaX Yes, that's it: Command line mounting of device and mount point works, but nothing so far using fstab works (for these three partitions).

@telcoM I've never done this before... /proc/mounts is a link that points to /proc/self/mounts. In /proc/self, there are three entries starting with mount: mounts, mountinfo and mountstats. a cat of mounts gives all the mounted "devices" and adding a grep yields this line: /dev/sdb3 /disks/users ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0    But I don't know how that helps.

It is a positive proof that the filesystem type and device name are correct. So that makes me think the sdb disk might be a bit slow to spin up, so when the automatic mount attempt by /etc/fstab happens, the disk might not be quite ready yet. But once you get in to mount it manually, it would be fully spun up and ready to work.

@telcoM Creative thinking! ... I don't do it often enough to remember the command name off the top of my head but I know there's a utility intended to observe and change settings on disks, and I vaguely seem to recall disks can be told to save power and spin up slowly. So this warrants looking into since the disk was in other service prior to this.  ...If you recall the utility's name, that would be handy, but I probably won't get to this again until tomorrow morning.
